# Obtaining MAC address in android without using WifiInfo instance

Tags: java, android, android-layout, networking, android-intent

I am trying to get the MAC address of my android device without relying on `myWifiInfo.getMacAddress()`

Following is the code I use:

```
       try{
            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inet);
            byte[] address = ni.getHardwareAddress();
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("MyActivity",e.toString());
        }
```

I get the following exception:

```
08-01 06:10:56.239: WARN/System.err(23164): at   java.net.NetworkInterface.rethrowAsSocketException(NetworkInterface.java:212)
08-01 06:10:56.239: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:178)
08-01 06:10:56.239: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.net.NetworkInterface.getByName(NetworkInterface.java:118)
08-01 06:10:56.239: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfacesList(NetworkInterface.java:270)
08-01 06:10:56.239: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.net.NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(NetworkInterface.java:228)
08-01 06:10:56.239: WARN/System.err(23164): at com.example.MyActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:82)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at com.example.MyActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:43)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:163)                       
08-01 06:10:56.247: WARN/System.err(23164): ... 12 more
```

I have given the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The exception is thrown from the following line in the code above:

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inet);
```

When I log the inet address, I get the same as `localhost/127.0.0.1`

Can someone please point out the reason for this issue and the solution for the same?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: you can also use Bluetooth API for obtaining MAC address

Comment: thanks for the info. but I am trying to understand the cause of the issue I explained and possible solution for the same

Comment: just a guess try giving `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission in your code.

Comment: that was a correct guess. Unfortunately I get `byte[] address = ni.getHardwareAddress();` as null. So, is it mandatory that I should use the WifiInfo instance to get MAC address of android hardware?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try following Bluetooth API code to get the MAC address,

```
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapther; 

mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceMacAddress = mBtAdapter.getAddress();
```

Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this retrieve the mac address for the bluetooth receiver, instead of for the wifi?

Comment: @MrThys it retrieve's the device's MAC address, which is same.

Comment: I don't think so, when I check the hardware info (in settings) on my phone (HTC One X) there is mac address for the wifi AND the bluetooth, and they are not the same

Comment: @Lucifer : 2 issues (1)As  MrThys said, it gives different addresses (2) It gives null pointer exception, when you have not enabled the Bluetooth in your device atleast for once.

Answer (score 0):

You can read `/sys/class/net/eth0/address` as a text file and this file contains the `ethernet-MAC-address` of `eth0` interface, if your device have ethernet hardware.

Sample code may help you:

```
public String getMac()
{
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sys/class/net/eth0/address"));
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
        }
        reader.close();
        return fileData.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The Wifi must be enabled to make it work, if it is off then this file is missing.

Comment: i have used this same piece of code in a device in which only ethernet port is available. also, the same code works fine on a device with wifi+ethernet (and wifi is turned-off). so i am sure the file-reading is not dependent on wifi on/off status

Comment: I am now working with device that have only wifi and BT available (android 2.3.4), and I have seen in DDMS this file was disappearing and appearing once wifi was turned on/off. I also have experienced this in java code.

Comment: if your device don't have ethernet, then this code won't help you

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getMacAddressFromEtcFile(){
        try {
            return loadFileAsString("/sys/class/net/eth0/address").toUpperCase().substring(0, 17);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


 public static String loadFileAsString(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException{
        StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int numRead = 0;
        while((numRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1){
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
        }
        reader.close();
        return fileData.toString();
    }
```